# Imageview is not displaying proper image from URL

Tags: java, android

Here is the adapter class where I set image from URL:

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmployeeAdapter.MyViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private List<EmployeeList.details>detailsList;
   
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public CircleImageView image;
        
        private MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            image = view.findViewById(R.id.employeeImg);           
        }

    public EmployeeAdapter(Context context, List<EmployeeList.details> details) {
        this.context = context;
        this.detailsList = details;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.employee_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final EmployeeList.details details = detailsList.get(position);

        String strUserImg=detailsList.get(position).getImage();

        if(strUserImg.length()>0){
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(strUserImg)
                    .into(holder.image);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return detailsList.size();
    } 
}
```

I am trying to set image for circleimageview from imageurl. The image is loading from URL, also it's displaying in circleimageview but the issue is when I scroll down and up after scrolling the image from URL is changing the position if there is no URL.

For example: third position image is displaying in first position.

How can I sort out this issue?

Comment: Can you share the code of the Activity/Fragment where you are implementing this RecyclerView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy solution would be to add an else condition to the if block

```
if(strUserImg.length()>0){
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(strUserImg)
                    .into(holder.image);
} else {
      Glide.with(context)
                    .load(<PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE>)
                    .into(holder.image);


}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution but image is taking time to display in imageview

Comment: It takes time since the image is fetched from a url and glide does an asynchronous call to get the image. The behavior is normal, you can try showing a loading placeholder while the image is being fetched

Answer (score 0):

```
    final EmployeeList.details details = detailsList.get(position);
    String strUserImg=details.getImage();

    if(strUserImg.length()>0){
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(strUserImg)
                .into(holder.image);
    } else {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(<YOUR_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE>)
                .into(holder.image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `if(strUserImg.length()>0){`, if `strUserImg.length()` <= 0, the code will simply reuses the previous viewholder and load the same image. Try using `Glide.clear`

```
if(strUserImg.length()>0){
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(strUserImg)
        .into(holder.image);
} else {
    Glide.clear(holder.image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strUserImg!=null){
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(strUserImg)
        .into(holder.image);
} else {
     Glide.with(context)
        .load(your_place_holder)
        .into(holder.image);
}
```